# Java: Is it more appropriate to store constants in an non-method interface or class?

Tags: java, oop

This question has been bothering me forever. I can wait to hear the responses. I see this too often

```
public interface Istuff
{
    public static final int STATE_B = 4;
    public static final int STATE_L = 5;
    public static final int STATE_U = 6;
}
```

and also this one

```
public class MyStuffConstants
{
    public static final String STATUS = "STATUS";
    public static final String RUNNING = "RUNNING";

}
```

Comment: Ahh.. I didnt want to hear that! If you have an interface your saying "I have this contract - abide by it or dont use it" which makes sense if you have methods. Right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say [**Enum**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html). as their sole purpose is to represent fixed set of constants.

Simple Example:

```
enum Season { WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL }
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. That would make sense to me also

Comment: I'd say the main purpose of enums was to represent a fixed value set, which was possible in other languages. I think this is different from a fixed set of constants, in that a constant is always a value, with a name attached to it. You don't need to have values in enums. While they are nice for storing extra values that are attached to the value names, I don't think they're practical as a general substitution for constant, fixed set or not.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `enum` for that. It's too powerful not to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use interfaces for that. It gets very messy as soon as you have many interfaces (which may come from interfaces extending other interfaces) : you need then to precise in what interfaces to pick the constants which nullifies the benefits of defining the constants in an interface.

The clean solution is to have a non instanciable class for that. Of course, when an enumeration is applicable (that is, the values are different possible values in the same semantic field), you should use an enum. But don't use an enum for this kind of constant :

```
public final static int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 666;
```

Comment: Note that you can't have top-level class as static. You can have `static nested class`.

Comment: cant we define default with this way in an enum ,, enum val{
WIDTH(666);
val(int  i){
 
}
??

Answer (score 2):

If you can also associate arbitrary data with your enum constants by adding a constructor:

```
public enum Season {

    WINTER(1, 15), SPRING(2, 92), SUMMER(3, 40), FALL(50, 9);

    private final int foo;
    private final int bar;

    Season(int foo, int bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public int getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the IStuff example I think enums is kind of awkward if you don't actually need the whole exclusive ordering bit - you'll end up basically creating a class for wrapping an integer.

The MyStuffs example makes sense to make an enum out of, as long as the name of the constant works for you.

It comes down to who will be using the constants - sometimes it makes sense to use constants internally in a class (avoiding magic values). In that case "private static final * *;" works fine.

If you want the constants to be useful as part of an API then sure do constants as in iStuff (btw you can lose the "public static final" bit, which is default when putting them like that in an interface).

Edit: and if you don't have an interface to begin with, and you have constants that clearly belong to a specific, even though the constants need to be public, I don't see the need to create a separate interface just to have somewhere to put the constants. If however the constants will be used in two or more classes/apis and belong in one place more than another, then sure why not put the constants in a separate interface.

I think the concept of constants is too complex to be answered by a general "do this" statement.